# Making css numbers to look pretty

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the code which is in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dQR9T/8337/)

```css
.numberCircle {
  border-radius: 10%;
  behavior: url(PIE.htc);
  /* remove if you don't care about IE8 */
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
  display: table;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  background: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #666;
  color: #666;
  text-align: center;
  font: 28px Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="numberCircle">368585760</div>
```

Thanks to the one who had this fiddle, I updated it with my changes:, now without adding additional `html elements`, is it possible to design every single number inside the box to look like this

http://prntscr.com/gi26iz

I was trying to use the css3 first child, 2nd child etc etc but I am not sure what to do.

Comment: Use a font and apply it to everything

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the relevant code directly in the question body.

Comment: No, not with CSS. You're limited to the first number using `::first-letter`. You can wrap the numbers in separate tags and then use `:nth-child()` but you've already said no extra html tags.

Answer (score 3):

If you can't change the markup, you can try this with jquery - *replacing* the contents of the div with each digit *wrapped* into a `span`.

See a demo to get you started:

```js
var html = $('.numberCircle')
  .text()
  .split('').map(function(e){
     return "<span>" + e + "</span>";
  }).join('');
$('.numberCircle').html(html);
```

```css
.numberCircle span {
  border-radius: 10%;
  behavior: url(PIE.htc);
  /* remove if you don't care about IE8 */
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
  /*display: table;*/
  display: inline-block; /* CHANGED */
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 15px;
  background: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #666;
  color: #666;
  text-align: center;
  font: 28px Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="numberCircle">368585760</div>
```

Comment: Nice. Good idea

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way to do is use javascript to add styling to each elements. There is no css like :nth-letter

Comment: sorry @kukkuz i can not add a comment yet